# debugging icons using chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Say i have an icon in a webpage and i would like to figure out what happens when i click that, how do i debug that with chrome debugger? Assuming that i have the non-minified code for the webpage.

i tried to do inspect element and attaching to event handlers which doesn help much.

```
<span id="__icon84" data-ui="__icon84" data-ui-icon-content="" class="UiIcon UiIconMirrorInRTL" style="font-family:'icons'"></span>
```

all i get is that the icon used is __icon84.

PS: i am new to JS.

Comment: first find the javascript file the handles the click event
then using the chrome debugging tool you can use the break point functionality.

or you could insert the javascript code

debugger;

on the click event function

you will notice in the chrome debugging tools
that it will stop the execution of the script once it
has reach the debugger or the break points of the script

Comment: @soproni like i had mentioned in my description. the events are not helping much..

Comment: can you give me the link of the website you are trying to debug.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Event Listener Breakpoints` sidebar pane in the `Sources` panel. Expand "Mouse" and check the "click" box. Then the debugger should break whenever you enter a "click" event handler.